# How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object with optional attribute order

Tags: c#, list, sorting, generics

Let say I have a base class and two derived classes.

```
public abstract class BaseClass 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Owner { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : BaseClass
{
    [CustomAttr(Order = 2)]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [CustomAttr(Order = 5)]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public string Other { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : BaseClass
{
    [CustomAttr(Order = 3)]
    public string Organization { get; set; }

    [CustomAttr(Order = 1)]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
}
```

By default, the order of the properties is based on how they are declared in the class so if in the `BaseClass` since there is no `[CustomAttr(Order = n)` assume this is the correct order.

Now since in the two derived class, there is a defined custom attribute that will identify the property order the behavior should be sorted by:

1. Id
2. Country
3. Name
4. Description
5. Amount
6. Owner
7. DateAdded
8. Other

So what will happen those with `CustomAttr[(Order = n)]` should be placed to their property order and for those that do not have we assume they are in there proper order. This should also have a similar behavior if I use the `Bar` class.

The use case of this is I need to have the right order of the properties of the class in the `List<T>` to have the correct order of column in an excel file.

What I did is I have to add the `CustomAttr[(Order = n)]` to all of the properties to sort them however this is a tedious thing to do which require you to change the order of all properties if you try to change one of the property order.

Any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you post the code for `CustomAttr` as well since it looks relevant to you issue. Plus, you would have to write some logic there to 'assume' a default ordering in case not specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to read the names of all of the properties of a class in the order they are declared. You can then elaborate this in your logic and sort the fields accordingly.

Try the following:

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(Bar).GetProperties();
foreach (var propInfo in propertyInfos)
    Console.WriteLine(propInfo.Name);
```

This will write all of the properties in the `Bar` class (this is just an example, you can replace that by any of your classes), including the properties inherited from its superclass (`BaseClass`). Expected output:

```
Organization
Keywords
Id
Name
Description
Owner
DateAdded
```

Notice though that this method lists the properties from the class first, and then goes up in the hierarchy listing each superclass (this is why `Bar`'s members are being listed before `BaseClass`'s members). You can elaborate the code a little bit more to change the order according to your needs.

The following (non-optimized) code first creates a list of all of the given class' hierarchy, starting from the base class towards the given `T` class. After that, it iterates over each of the classes, discovering only the properties defined in each class (I'm passing the `GetProperties()` method a parameter stating that I just want the properties that are **public**, **instance/non-static**, and **declared on the specific class I am currently consulting**).

```
private static void ListAllOrderedPropertiesOfType(Type targetType)
{
    // Generate a list containing the whole hierarchy of classes, from the base type to the type T
    var typesList = new List<Type>();
    for (Type t = targetType; t != typeof(Object); t = t.BaseType)
        typesList.Insert(0, t);

    // Iterate from the base type to type T, printing the properties defined for each of the types
    foreach (Type t in typesList)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        foreach (var propInfo in propertyInfos)
            Console.WriteLine(propInfo.Name);
    }
}
```

So if you wanted to know all of the properties for type `Bar`, ordered from the topmost base class towards the `Bar` class, you could call this method like that:

```
ListAllOrderedPropertiesOfType(typeof(Bar));
```

Expected output would be the properties in the following order:

```
Id
Name
Description
Owner
DateAdded
Organization
Keywords
```

With that you know the fields' declaration order and their custom orders (through your `CustomAttr` attribute). You can now implement a sort method to order the fields according to their declaration orders and `CustomAttr` orders, according to your needs.

But I guess this is a little beyond the scope of my answer (which intends to show you how to get the order of declaration of properties, from a base class towards any given specific class).

Answer (score 1):

I created a generic solution by reading your attribute and creating a comparer what will compare in the order of your attribute order. in the contructor of the comparer I am reading over reflection your attributes. While comparing I take one property after the other and when equal (zero), I go to the next.
The logic works also with inheritance, so even on the base class you can have CustomAttr.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class CustomAttr : Attribute
{
    public CustomAttr():base()
        {}

    public CustomAttr(int Order)
    {
        this.Order = Order;
    }
    public int Order {get ; set ; }

}
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [CustomAttr(Order = 20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Owner { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : BaseClass
{
    [CustomAttr(Order = 2)]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [CustomAttr(Order = 5)]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public string Other { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : BaseClass
{
    [CustomAttr(Order = 3)]
    public string Organization { get; set; }

    [CustomAttr(Order = 1)]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
}
class app
{


    static void Main()
    {
        List<Bar> listToOrder = new List<Bar>();
        listToOrder.Add(new Bar() { Id = 5, Keywords = "Hello", Organization = "Arlando" });
        listToOrder.Add(new Bar() { Id = 12, Keywords = "Table", Organization = "Fuelta" , Name = "Deep"});
    listToOrder.Add(new Bar() { Id = 12, Keywords = "Table", Organization = "Fuelta", Name = "Inherit" });
    listToOrder.Add(new Bar() { Id = 1, Keywords = "Muppet", Organization = "Coke" });
        listToOrder.Add(new Bar() { Id = 6, Keywords = "Grumpy", Organization = "Snow" });
        listToOrder.Add(new Bar() { Id = 9, Keywords = "Johny", Organization = "White" });
        listToOrder.Add(new Bar() { Id = 12, Keywords = "Table", Organization = "Bruno" });
        listToOrder.Add(new Bar() { Id = 12, Keywords = "Table", Organization = "Fuelta" });
        listToOrder.Add(new Bar() { Id = 7, Keywords = "Set", Organization = "Voltra" });
        listToOrder.Add(new Bar() { Id = 45, Keywords = "Brr", Organization = "Elvis" });
        listToOrder.Add(new Bar() { Id = 15, Keywords = "Tsss", Organization = "Marion" });

        OrderComparer<Bar> myOrder = new OrderComparer<Bar>();
        listToOrder.Sort(myOrder);

        foreach (Bar oneBar in listToOrder)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(oneBar.Id + " " + oneBar.Keywords + " " + oneBar.Organization);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private class OrderComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
    {
        SortedList<int, PropertyInfo> sortOrder = new SortedList<int, PropertyInfo>();

        public OrderComparer()
        {
            Type objType = typeof(T);
            foreach (PropertyInfo oneProp in objType.GetProperties())
            {
                CustomAttr customOrder = (CustomAttr) oneProp.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(CustomAttr), true);
                if (customOrder == null) continue;
                sortOrder.Add(customOrder.Order, oneProp);
            }
        }
        public int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            Type objType = typeof(T);
            int result = 0;
            int i = 0;

            while (result == 0 && i < sortOrder.Count)
            {
                result = ((IComparable)sortOrder.ElementAt(i).Value.GetValue(x)).CompareTo(sortOrder.ElementAt(i).Value.GetValue(y));
                i++;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See this example for order using List with system.Linq

```
class Program
{

    class test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string Owner { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        List<test> listOrder = new List<test>();
        listOrder.Add(new test() { Id = 1, Name = "john", Description = "test", Owner = "test", DateAdded = DateTime.Now });
        listOrder.Add(new test() { Id = 1, Name = "max", Description = "test1", Owner = "test1", DateAdded = DateTime.Now });
        listOrder.Add(new test() { Id = 1, Name = "phil", Description = "test2", Owner = "test2", DateAdded = DateTime.Now });

        List<test> sortbyName = listOrder.OrderBy(item => item.Name).ToList();

        List<test> sortbyDescription = listOrder.OrderBy(item => item.Description).ToList();

        List<test> sortbyOwner = listOrder.OrderBy(item => item.Owner).ToList();

    }
}
```